# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing - CORS request did not succeed

Tags: node.js, api, rest, meteor, cors

I am facing issue calling Remote API from localhost.

I am using `nimble:restivus` package

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

As per documentation I am setting:

`enableCors: true`

in order to allow access from any origin. But no luck.

This is the error I am getting in browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading 
the remote resource at http://192.168.18.20:9000/api/getUsers. 
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Here is my server side code:

```
myApi = new Restivus({
    
    apiPath: 'api/',
    enableCors: true,
    useDefaultAuth: false,
    prettyJson: true,
    defaultOptionsEndpoint: {
        action: function() {
            this.response.writeHead(201, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Z-Key, Authorization"
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            });
            this.done();
            return {
                status: "success",
                "data": {
                    "message": "We love OPTIONS"
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my client side code:

```
$.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://example.com/api/getUsers",
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI"
          }
          data: {},
          success: function (){
            alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
          }
        });
```

If I send nothing in header, the request succeed otherwise it gives error in browser console.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your framework must be misconfigured, somehow. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Restivus. Any chance you could test this in Chrome? It will fail there as well, but Chrome's CORS error messages are more informative that Firefox's, in my opinion.

Comment: Shoud `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` not be `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` (a colon rather than a comma)?

Comment: Same remark about `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Z-Key, Authorization"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` Header since you are sending an `Authorization` header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that when you send an authorization header, the allow origin header must match the requesting domain. All requests will be denied when the header is `*`

Comment: like this: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:": "true"?

Comment: I tried this but I am getting this error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.18.20:9000/api/getUsers. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: Sorry, see edit.

Comment: I tried using this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://192.168.18.20:5000", but still same error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.18.20:9000/api/getUsers. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: for a qualified origin you need to add the protocol.

Comment: Can you please explain the protocol? Any example you can show me?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is unlikely to help here, because the OP's request uses the Bearer authentication scheme, which isn't considered as "credentials" by the CORS protocol.

Comment: @jub0bs So what should I do here?

Comment: @StormTrooper The first thing would be to edit your question and add the full message of the CORS error you get.

Comment: @jub0bs I updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: @KellyCopley i didnt down vote. I still need to find answer to it

Comment: @KellyCopley but the matter is that your solution still doesnt work. I have updated my question with all the latest changes

Comment: @StormTrooper I didn't assume you had downvoted.

Comment: If you have a public repo, I'd be more than happy to take a look and see what I can determine to be the issue.

Comment: Alright I can build some repo for you. I need some time for that

Comment: For sure. You can find me as copleykj on GitHub.

Comment: @KellyCopley It depends on the authentication scheme. Basic is considered ambient authority; it will be sent by the browser in a credentialed request. Not so for the Bearer authentication scheme.

Comment: @KellyCopley Assuming that the preflight succeeds, `Authorization: Bearer foo` [gets sent even in a non-credentialed request](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=GET&requestUseCORS=1&requestSendCredentials=&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=GET&preflightAllowHeaders=Authorization&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&responseAllowCredentials=&responseExposeHeaders=&requestHeaderName=Authorization&requestHeaderValue=Bearer+foo).

Comment: *when you send an authorization header, the allow origin header must match the requesting domain. All requests will be denied when the header is \*.* This too is [incorrect/imprecise](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=GET&requestUseCORS=1&requestSendCredentials=&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=*&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=GET&preflightAllowHeaders=Authorization&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=*&responseAllowCredentials=&responseExposeHeaders=&requestHeaderName=Authorization&requestHeaderValue=Basic+value).