# 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' when testing Firebase Cloud Functions using local emulator

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following CORS error when trying to invoke my callable function locally using the firebase cloud function emulator with my react app:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-xxxx-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/getSignedUrls. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 302.`

Here is my cloud function:

/functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()

exports.getSignedUrls = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const cloudfrontAccessKeyId = "XXXXXXXXX"
    let cloudfrontPrivateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'private_key.pem'))
    const signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(cloudfrontAccessKeyId, cloudfrontPrivateKey)
    const distName = "xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"
    const s3Path = data.path 
    let cfObjectUrl = 'https://' + distName + '/' + s3Path
    const twoDays = 2*24*60*60*1000
    const signedUrl = signer.getSignedUrl({
    url: cfObjectUrl,
    expires: Math.floor((Date.now() + twoDays)/1000)
    })
    return {url: signedUrl}
})
```

Here is where I create a reference to my apps cloud functions:

/src/firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
import {getFunctions} from 'firebase/functions'

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  authDomain: "xxxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",

  databaseURL: "https://xxx-xxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",

  projectId: "xxxx-xxxx",

  storageBucket: "xxxx-xxxx.appspot.com",

  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",

  appId: "1:938967916081:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

  measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxx"

})

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const db = getDatabase(app)
export const functions = getFunctions(app)

export default app
```

And here is the component in which I'm attempting to call my cloud function:

/src/components/SignedUrlTest.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {httpsCallable} from 'firebase/functions'
import {functions} from '../firebase'

class SignedUrlTest extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { url: null}
        this.getUrl = this.getUrl.bind(this)
    }

    getUrl(){
        var getSignedUrls = httpsCallable(functions, 'getSignedUrls');
        getSignedUrls({path: "Melissa-OShaughnessy-6-1024x683.jpg"
        }).then((result) => { console.log(result.data) })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.getUrl}>geturl</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignedUrlTest;
```

I've poured over the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), but can't seem to figure out why I'm unable to call my function using the client SDK.  I have tested a locally emulated 'onRequest' cloud function in the same environment and was able to get an appropriate response using my web browser, but I can't figure out how to invoke an 'onCall' function from my app.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: According to the error, you are missing the `CORS` header in your code. Cross Origin Resource Sharing, is a mechanism for browsers to let a site running at origin A to request resources from origin B. Check this [thread](https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-accesscontrolalloworigin-header) which can be very useful.

Comment: Also, check this 3 stackoverflow cases that can be useful. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959912/ajax-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851174/cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing-cors-request-did-not-succeed).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the solutions mentioned in this thread:

[Enabling CORS in Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

Especially the one, going to the GCP console and setting the cloud function invoker setting to "allUsers".

Comment: This is not a good solution because it changes to onRequest, which is not longer an http callable, which is supposed to automatically handle cors.